# How can I efficiently find a matrix D such that the cost function $||(M-D\cdot N)||$ is minimized?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Suppose that $M \in R^{P\,\text{x}\,K}$, $N \in R^{Q\,\text{x}\,K}$
, for P not necessarily having to equal Q, 
thus $D \in R^{P\,\text{x}\,Q}$

then given N and M matrices, let $C = M-D\cdot N$ = $\{C_{i,j}\}$

If the Cost function is defined as the norm of $C$
 = norm of $(M-D\cdot N)$ = $\sum_{j=1}^{K}(\sum_{i=1}^{P}|c_{i,j}|^{2})^{1/2}$, then how can I efficiently find $D$ that minimizes such cost?

Comment: There's a problem with the dimensions of what's in the determinant.

Comment: Why don't you use different letters for the dimensions and the matrices?

Comment: There was a lot of errors in writing the question and I fixed it.

Comment: Are you talking about Matrix Multiplication or [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it as 
$$
\|M-DN\|_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^P\|m_i^T-d_i^TN\|_2^2,
$$
where $m_i$ and $d_i$ are the $i$th rows of the matrices $M$ and $D$, respectively. So it is clear that this is equivalent to $P$ independent linear least squares problems with solutions given by
$$
d_i=N^{\dagger T}m_i,
$$
where $N^\dagger$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $N$.

Comment: If I find the pseudo-inverse of N, then can't I just find the matrix D via matrix multiplication of M * N^(dagger)? instead of having to transpose so many times?

Comment: @KevvyKim $D=N^{\dagger T}M$, or $D^T=M^TN^{\dagger}$. In practice, you don't want to construct the pseudo-inverse explicitly. The answer only tells you the expression for $D$. The way how you compute it is something else.

Comment: I was thinking of explicitly finding the pseudo-inverse via Singular Value Decomposition which has about time complexity of O(N^3). Are there any other methods to find D? I just can't think of how I can do that without compute the pseudo-inverse explicitly though.

Comment: @KevvyKim You can use any method for solving linear least squares problems, e.g., methods based on the [QR factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Orthogonal_decomposition_methods).

Comment: @Pavel May I know in the expression $\|M-DN\|_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^P\|m_i^T-d_i^TN\|_2^2$, whether $d_{i}^{T}$ should be $d_i$? It because $d_i$ is a row vector  and its size is 1 by Q. Then $d_{i}^{T}$ is Q by 1 column vector. Then I think it should write $d_{i} N$ for valid vector-matrix multiplication?

Comment: @nam Right, may be confusing. I meant that $d_i$ is a row of $D$ but considering it as a column vector.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, what if he meant [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))? How would you solve it then? Thought about extending everything into Vectors and Diagonal Matrices.